# How to pass gobject.Gtype arguments to a Gtk.ListStore in a function

Tags: python, gtk3

I would like to pass to a function a list of types and data to register a Gtk.ListStore object.
It works with a single type, passed directly as an argument, but as soon as there are several types it is necessary to use a container (list?). And in this case, I do not know how to rebase these types (str, int, etc.) into gobject.Gtype.
If anyone has a solution that would be great.
Sample code below.

thank you in advance.

```
# Fonctions
def initListStore(lesTypes, laListe):
  leStore = Gtk.ListStore(gobject.Gtype(lesTypes))
  for item in laListe:
    leStore.append(item)
  return leStore

# Appli
liste = [('Albert','Einstein'),('Salvador','Dali'),('Alexandre','Dumas')]
lesTypes = 'str str'
lsAuteurs = initListStore(lesTypes,liste)
for row in lsAuteurs:
  print (row[:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
def initListStore(lesTypes, laListe):
    leStore = Gtk.ListStore()
    leStore.set_column_types(lesTypes)
    for item in laListe:
      leStore.append(item)
    return leStore

# Appli
liste = [('Albert','Einstein'),('Salvador','Dali'),('Alexandre','Dumas')]
lesTypes = (str, str)
lsAuteurs = initListStore(lesTypes,liste)
for row in lsAuteurs:
    print (row[:])
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposal that I had already tried, and in this case I recover this error: TypeError: Item 0: Must be gobject.GType, not str

Comment: @phdb44 Try putting my edited example code in a python file and tell me what you get. It works for me.

Comment: Ok it's time for me to go back to sleep ... I had to go wrong by writing the code. Here I just retest your code and it works very well. Thank you very much for your help. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I improved the function by completely outsourcing the management of the listStore to the function itself, which now only receives one parameter: the list of data. A big thank you to **theGtknerd** who unlocked me.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
def initListStore(laListe):
    types = []
    ligne = laListe[0]
    for mot in ligne:
      types.append(type(mot))
    leStore = Gtk.ListStore()
    leStore.set_column_types(types)
    for item in laListe:
      leStore.append(item)
    return leStore

# Appli
liste = [('Albert','Einstein'),('Salvador','Dali'),('Alexandre','Dumas')]
lsAuteurs = initListStore(liste)
for row in lsAuteurs:
    print (row[:])
```